# Qt designer: nested widget is not a member?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

Im using Qt Creator 3.2.1.
Using the Qt Designer I made the basic design: I added a custom widget (*CustomWidget widget*) to my *mainwindow* by adding a normal QWidget and promoting it to my custom one.
Within that custom widget I added a QGraphicsView (*QGraphicsView view*).

The Object browser of Qt Designer displays the hierarchy of the items correctly: *view* within *widget* and *widget* within *mainwindow*.

However, the ui_mainwindow.h that is generated by the form gives me:

```
// in ui_mainwindow.h
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    CustomWidget *widget;
    QGraphicsView *view;
    // ...
};
```

When I really expected:

```
// in ui_mainwindow.h
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    CustomWidget *widget;
    // ...
};

// in customwidget.h
class CustomWidget
{
public:
    QGraphicsView *view;
    // ...
};
```

Is a nested widget of another widget not supposed to be a member of it?

How to adjust my class design in the Qt Designer to make *view* member of *widget*?

Answer (score 0):

In `Qt`, the rule which is used in defining widget hierarchies is not containment but parenting. `widget1` of type `WidgetType1` will be drawn inside `widget2` of type `WidgetType2` if `widget2` is the parent of `widget1`, not if the class `WidgetType2` contains a member of type `WidgetType2`. `widget2` can be set parent of `widget1` by passing `widget2` as parent in the constructor of `widget2` or by using `widget2.setParent(widget1);`. Layouts also can define `Parent/child` hierarchies.

Yes, you can have types of objects which contain and define other objects, but if you don't pass `this` as parent to the member objects, the member objects won't be drawn inside the container class type widgets.

In your case there is no need to have multiple classes, you just have to make the objects you want to be containers parents to objects you want to be children. For more info I recommend reading the `Qt` documentation for [Layout Management](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html) and [Object Trees & Ownership](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The widget drawing isn't problem.
The problem is that Qt Designer doesn't contain a nested widget into the parent widget which would make sense in my opinion.

Imaging you wanted to create multiple instances of CustomWidget.
It just makes more sense to have QGraphicsView *view contained within it.